# How to put two x,y coordinate values as one in scatter chart in excel

Tags: excel, scatter-plot

I want to do something like this

I want to make a point `x,y` coordinate for one and `x,y` for another and show two points in a single scatter chart.
I am unable to figure out how to do this

```
x  y         x2  y2
1  1          1   8
```

From data above  I need to show two points `(1,1)` and `(1,8)`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your data layout, the data points can be added as one series or as two series. Steps vary with your Excel version.

Try this: click an empty cell that has no data in neighbor cells. Click Insert > XY Scatter chart. This will create a blank XY chart. Now add the series.

Right-click the chart > Select Data > Add > select the range(s) for the X and Y values. Repeat for any other series.

If the data is in one contiguous table, you only need one series.

[image]